# explanation of D_GNU_SOURCE Why to use it and when?

Tags: c, linux

I know it is a Macro we are passing to a function. How do you explain what is the use of this macro, and in which  scenario i have to use this ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas applications developed conforming to [POSIX.1](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1003.1-2008.html) - (IEEE 1003.1-2008, ISO/IEC 9945:2009) and / or [Single Unix Specification 2008](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/jsp/publications/PublicationDetails.jsp?catalogno=t101) (ISO/IEC 9945:2009 with X/Open Curses) help ensure how portable your application is. The `_GNU_SOURCE` will most likely limits source code usage to GNU/Linux and GNU/Hurd systems, unless additional work is done to address the non-portability of such functionality on other platforms.

Some companies, and government / military contracts may require certain platform standards to be used.

If you are developing an Open Source / Free Software application that you wish to be available on multiple Unix and Unix-like systems (including Microsoft Windows NT, 2000, and newer which have a POSIX compatibility available) then limiting your development to POSIX.1 library functions makes this an easier task. Other targets include the free/open BSD platforms NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, DragonflyBSD, as well as the commercial Unix systems (Solaris, AIX, HP/UX, etc.) that do not include `_GNU_SOURCE` functionality.

If you use an altered functionality of a portable function, I can't think of an example but I believe they do exist, it may create subtle bugs in non-GNU platforms.

So in general, if your development is already locked into GNU / Linux and GNU / Hurd then feel free to use such extensions, but avoid such usages for any applications that may be deployed on other Unix and Unix-like operating systems.

I do work on a large-ish code base that has been ported from two other Unix platforms to Linux, and we do use `_GNU_SOURCE` extensions sparingly, though most of the development is limited to modern POSIX or IEEE 1003.1 / Single Unix Spec and C99 (Standard C Library) standards for future compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Between, i tried the following code:                                                       #include <stdio.h>
int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{
 char *p;
                                                                      asprintf (&p, "%s", "Welcome");
 printf ("String is %s ", p);

}
gcc -o mysample mysample.c   : i m able to compile and execute the code. I have included nowhere _GNU_SOURCE in the soure code, not i used macro while compiling. But still how it is compiling ?

Comment: The GCC documentation, on [C Dialect Options](http://goo.gl/z0Piy) lists that 'gnu89' / 'gnu90' is default (in version 4.6.2 and many other versions as well). `gcc -v` to check your version, and `cpp -dM </dev/null` to look for predefined headers. _GNU_SOURCE is not defined, so as the gcc manual explains extensions that don't conflict with ANSI/ISO standards are allowed by default. `_GNU_SOURCE` would also allow GNU extensions that modify or conflict with ANSI/ISO standards.

Comment: Regarding the "altered functionality of a portable function": I was interested in finding an example of functions with different declarations under different Feature Test Macros, and found one: [mmap is declared differently depending on the POSIX compliance level, at least on Solaris](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/standardheaderfiles-453865.html?printOnly=1).

Answer (score 5):

`_GNU_SOURCE` enables GNU extensions to the C and OS standards supported by the GNU C library, such as `asprintf`. Define it when you're using such non-standard functions and macros.

Comment: What is disadvantage of using such non-standard ?.  It is not portable across platform?

Comment: @Whoami: non-portability, indeed. The manpages for the C library document which standards functionality adheres to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Between, i tried the following code: #include <stdio.h> int main ( int argc, char ** argv) { char *p; asprintf (&p, "%s", "Welcome"); printf ("String is %s ", p); } gcc -o mysample mysample.c : i m able to compile and execute the code. I have included nowhere _GNU_SOURCE in the soure code, nor i used macro while compiling. But still how it is compiling ?

Answer (score 4):

From `glibc` manual:

> Macro: **_GNU_SOURCE**
>
> If you define this macro, everything is included: ISO C89, ISO C99, POSIX.1, POSIX.2, BSD,      SVID, X/Open, LFS, and GNU extensions. In the cases where POSIX.1 conflicts with BSD, the POSIX definitions take precedence.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html

Answer (score 1):

Some functions not mandated by the standard are provided in libraries, but are only available when some feature test macro is defined. `_GNU_SOURCE` is one of the macros that makes such functions available.